# Can I fly back to a different country in Schengen zone post-covid rather than the country where I have the long-term residence permit?

Tags: schengen, international-travel, covid-19, long-stay-visas

I am originally from India and have a long-term residence permit for Germany (through work). Right now, I want to fly to move to Portugal for 1 month by flying to France first and then taking a separate flight from there (since there is no direct flight to Portugal).

Normally it should be fine, but I am not sure how the rules are post-COVID. Is it allowed? Is there some paperwork that I have to submit?

Comment: How long do you want to stay in France?

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I updated the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: You might want to avoid "move to," since that means "establish residence in," and people are going to tell you that you should be asking on [Expatriates.SE] even though you're only planning to be there for one month.  I would say "go to" or "visit."

Comment: If your residence permit is for Germany, there may be suspicions regarding your plan to go to Portugal instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I am originally from India and have a long-term residence permit for Germany (through work).

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> France: you can transit but not enter France. Note that if you need to pick up + recheck your luggages before flying from France to Portugal, then you're likely need to enter France. As recommended for many covid questions, it doesn't hurt to try to confirm with your airline(s) and embassies.

Also, still from IATA, you'll need to do the following paperwork:

> 4. A completed International Travel Certificate must be presented prior to boarding and to immigration upon arrival or when transiting
>    France. The certificate can be obtained at consulates or at
>    https://www.interieur.gouv.fr.
>
> - This does not apply to passengers arriving from Andorra, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Monaco, New Zealand, Rwanda, San
>   Marino, Switzerland, Thailand, Tunisia, United Kingdom, Uruguay,
>   Vatican City (Holy See) or an EEA Member State.
>
> 5. Passengers must complete a declaration on honor to state that they do not have symptoms of Coronavirus (COVID-19).

You can also check out https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/FRA